# Are Spring Integration Queue Channel Multithreaded

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-integration

I am trying to understand whether multiple threads can concurrently/parallelly messages from Spring Integration Queue Channel.
Suppose I have the following configuration :

```
<int:channel id="fooChannel">
   <int:queue />
 </int:channel>
```

From the documentation, I understand that by using a Queue Channel producer and consumer get decoupled and both happen in different threads.

My point of confusion is - Is there a way that Multiple threads can work on the messages stored in the queue channel. Something that we regularly do with JMS channels. (one/multiple producer & multiple consumer)

If it is not possible what is the recommended way to achieve concurrent processing of the messages in a queue channel

Answer (score 2):

The `QueueChannel` is backed by the `java.util.Queue` (the `LinkedBlockingQueue` by default), which is designed for multi-threaded interaction.

So, you definitely can send message to this channel from different threads.
And on the other hand it is also true: this channel works exactly as JMS queue: you can have several competitive consumers (`PollingConsumer` endpoints) and only one of them will poll and process a message from the queue.

Comment: So there cannot be multiple threads processing the multiple messages from the queue concurrently ? At a given time, there would only be 1 thread processing a single message ?

Comment: Correct. That a purpose of `queue` abstraction. Other threads may process other messages, concurrently

Comment: Sorry, but I am getting confused. When you say "Other threads may process other messages, concurrently", is this in context of a single Queue ? Let me rephrase my question - Can there be more one message (from the same queue channel) processed concurrently ? i.e. multiple threads concurrently processing different messages from the same queue ?

Comment: Right. That's how it works. Although they poll messages from queue exclusively, each of consumers may process its own message in parallel with other consumers processing different messages from the same queue. I don't know how else to explain you, but if you are familiar with JMS queue, you can fully apply those concepts for the `QueueChannel`