# How to make polling multi-thread on spring integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I have the following Spring Integration flow:

It gathers records from one database, converts to json and sends to another database.

The idea is to have 10 pollers (channel0 to 9). Each one is a `pollingFlowChanN` Bean. But I suspect they are sharing the same thread.

How to I make the polling multi-thread in this scenario?

```java
    private IntegrationFlow getChannelPoller(final int channel, final int pollSize, final long delay) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource(channel, pollSize), c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(delay)
                .transactional(transactionManager)))
                .split()
                .handle(intControleToJson())
                .handle(pgsqlSink)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingFlowChan0() {
        return getChannelPoller(0, properties.getChan0PollSize(), properties.getChan0Delay());
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pollingFlowChan1() {
        return getChannelPoller(1, properties.getChan1PollSize(), properties.getChan1Delay());
    }

   ....
```

Comment: I haven't used spring integration in many years, but I remember that the channel has to be a Queue Channel to support concurrency. Maybe this other questions sheds some light https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637435/are-spring-integration-queue-channel-multithreaded

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231128/why-does-the-sftp-outbound-gateway-not-start-working-as-soon-as-i-start-its-inte/69255243#69255243) - if you are using a recent version of Boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use the latest Spring Boot, which have a `TaskScheduler` auto-configured with one thread: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.spring-integration. That's the best guess why your tasks use the same thread.

See also answer here: [Why does the SFTP Outbound Gateway not start working as soon as I start its Integration Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231128/why-does-the-sftp-outbound-gateway-not-start-working-as-soon-as-i-start-its-inte/69255243#69255243)

Comment: I am on boot 2.5.5. I have added the `spring.task.execution.pool` configurations, but I see no threads on jvisualvm.

Comment: Not correct. Has to be `spring.task.scheduling.pool.size`. There is difference between a `TaskExecutor` and `TaskSchduler`.